# Yii2 Form submission through ajax

Tags: ajax, yii2

I have used check boxes in my gridview,like this

```
<?php
if(isset($dataProvider) && !empty($dataProvider)) {
 echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
             'header' => 'No.'],
             [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                    'header'=>'Select',
                    'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                            return ['value' => $model->dsItemId];
                    }
                ],

            [
               'label'=>'Category',
               'value' => function ($model) {
                   return $model->getdscategoryName();
               },
           ],
            'dsItemName',
            'qty',
            [
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'enableSorting' => false,
                'format' => 'image',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->getImageUrl(); 
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]); 
     echo Html::submitButton('Save',['id' => 'saveBtn','class' => 'btn btn-danger']);    
    }?>
```

When I'm selecting check boxes and select savebutton, it will go to this function given below,

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $('#saveBtn').click(function() { 
            var idVar = '';
            $("input[name='selection[]']").each( function () { 
                if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
                    if(idVar != '') {
                        idVar += ',' + $(this).val();
                    }else {
                        idVar = $(this).val();
                    }
                }
            });
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url:"<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['dsproductitems/setproduct'])?>",
                data: { dsItemId : idVar },
                success:function(data) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Here I'm trying to redirect my form to controller through ajax and the problem is, program control is failing to enter into flowing code.

```
$.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['dsproductitems/setproduct'])?>",
                    data: { dsItemId : idVar },
                    success:function(data) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
```

i'm failing to figure out why.. please help..

Comment: check what are are you getting in console?